# WagtailAdminPageForm and URL not saving in admin or passing to page

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a quick script that parses a JSON response from an API and adds it to a WagtailAdminPageForm, like so:

```
"""Flexible page."""
from django.db import models
import requests
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm

def get_mp3_choices():
    response = requests.get('https://api.somexamplepage.com')
    response.raise_for_status()
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    jsonResponse['results'][0]['audio']
    mp3_list = []
    return [
        (key['audio'], key['title'])
        for key in jsonResponse['results']
    ]  

class FlexPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    audioUrl = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_mp3_choices)

    class Meta:
        label = 'Select Audio for Player'

class FlexPage(Page):
    """Flexibile page class."""

    template = "flex/flex_page.html"

    # @todo add streamfields 
    # content = StreamField()
    base_form_class = FlexPageForm
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Flexbody = RichTextField(blank=True)
    bannerImage = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+"
    )
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("subtitle"),
        FieldPanel('Flexbody', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('bannerImage'),
    ]

    class Meta:  # noqa 
        verbose_name = "Flex Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Flex Pages"
```

The code works well and I'm able to see the returned list of MP3's within my admin panel. The problem, the selected MP3 is not being preserved when I save the page and, when I look in the sqlite table, I'm not seeing any record of the audioUrl. The following fields do show.

```
page_ptr_id subtitle    Flexbody    bannerImage_id
```

I've tried running migrations, but they aren't showing that I need to make any migrations. When I try to call the field within the Wagtail App:

```
<audio controls="" style="
  margin-bottom: 25px;
">
    <source
     src="{{ self.audioUrl }}"
     type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
```

The page loads but the developer tools list the URL as unknown.

Comment: You seem to have removed the `audioUrl` field from your model definition since the code you posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974174/wagtail-django-is-it-possible-to-populate-a-given-admin-fields-options-out-of-t/65974687?noredirect=1#comment116648264_65974687 . Was that intentional?

Comment: This was the issue, everything works now.